# Extend a GUI but now events are not working anymore

Tags: gwt

so I'm having a lot of classes that use the UIBinder to make the layout. Each one of those classes has a lot of added features in it though, so it's starting to get a little bit cluttered. My idea was to make a GUI class, where I will initialize the UiFields, and to make a class extend that one, and handle all the events in the subclass.

My problem is, the ClickHandlers are not working anymore. Anyone knows why?

Also is it bad practice to do it this way?

Comment: We can't answer your question unless you provide more specifics, like the code you're attempting to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to implement [HasHandlers](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/event/shared/HasHandlers.html) interface and make sure you GUI extends [composite](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html)